# Computation time between two methods

Tags: algorithm, matlab

Suppose we have two methods or algorithm. Suppose the code for each one as follow:

Method 1:

```
for i=0 to 100
 print i
 end for
```

Method 2:

```
int x=0
 w = x/2
 print w
```

What is the best approach to compare the computation time between method 1 & 2? 
I tried to use Matlab code:

```
t= cputime; 
 Method 1
 e = cputime-t
```

But I'm not sure if this is the correct way to compare the performance of those methods or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [this](http://www.mathworks.in/company/newsletters/articles/improvements-to-tic-and-toc-functions-for-measuring-absolute-elapsed-time-performance-in-matlab.html?s_cid=fb_wall_11-8-11_newsletter_tictoc) for complete info.

```
n = 1e4; %Higher number results in more accurate comparison
tic;
for t=1:n
  {method1}
end
toc;

tic;
for t=1:n
  {method2}
end
toc;
```

This will give you time-elapsed each time.

Comment: I tried this tic-toc ; but it gives different values each time I run the same script! I do not think its a robust method!

Comment: You're correct. More details on both the functions [here](http://forums.accelereyes.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2581&p=8043)

Comment: @Omar14 Note that you should run tic-toc on the time the script takes to execute many times, not just once.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin What do you mean of running the tic-toc and script many times?!

Comment: Also, to compare two methods, you also have to run the loops wrapping those methods for a larger number of iterations to get proper elapsed time.

Comment: @Omar14 I have edited the post to actually contain the loop. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `timeit` function, this comes with Matlab from 2013b onward but it is available on the [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function) if you are using an older version. This will correctly "warm up" the function for you before timing it and also outs your function in a loop internally and it reports the median time over many runs for you.

Otherwise the conventional method is to use `tic` and `toc` around a loop containing your function.

Comment: Note that for very short calculation times, the function call overhead that `timeit` requires may disturb your observations. (To see whether this is relevant for you, you can just try to run everything 10 times in the function and check whether the time goes up with a factor 10) If the overhead is a problem you will need to use loops around your code that is to be tested and you may as well switch to `tic toc`.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin `timeit` explicitly times, and compensates for, the function call overhead. It may not do that perfectly, but it will do it at least as well as you are likely to do by switching to `tic` and `toc` and compensating yourself. In fact `timeit` also compensates for the overhead in calling `tic` and `toc` as well. If `timeit` still thinks you are measuring something too short, it will  tell you.

Comment: **Clarification:** According to the documentation, [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) returns the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) time, not the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) (often thought of as the "*average*").